# Laravel Forge Nginx Config for SSL

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, server, laravel-forge

I usually don't post questions until I've researched it to death on the internet. I create a CSR using Laravel Forge, add the Certificate, activate it, edit the Nginx Config using these resources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192839/laravel-forge-ssl-certificate-not-working

^curl https://domain.com returns data

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /home/forge/example.com/public;

  # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/vgport.com/3042/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/vgport.com/3042/server.key;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  access_log off;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
}
```

I do 'service nginx restart' in command line, and go to /var/log/nginx/error.log and see the following error:

```
'conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored'
'conflicting server name "www.domain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored'
```

When I visit domain.com, it gets redirected to https://domain.com with 'This webpage has a redirect loop'. Clearly the Nginx redirect isn't working somehow but I've followed all the steps.

Please let me know what additional error logs and information I should post to troubleshoot this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you don't have any default configuration, something like /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay so the problem was simpler than I thought. I was using the free cloudflare dns pointing which didn't support ssl. I switched to using the namescheap dns and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

After spending some time researching nginx, I'd just like to add that when you add a cert, you have to manually press "Activate it" once downloaded.